# Obtener objeto entero de una relación con Query Builder en Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4, doctrine2, querybuilder

Estoy intentando obtener campos específicos de una entity con QueryBuilder y entre ellos tengo 2 relaciones con otras entities. El problema es que en esos campos me devuelve el id y no el objeto entero. Por ejemplo, con el Autor, me devuelve el id del autor y no el objeto entero de Autor como ocurre cuando no filtro por campos.

Os dejo aquí el código:

```php
$query = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('tp');
        return $query
            ->select("tp.id, tp.url, IDENTITY(tp.category) as category , tp.imageUrl, tp.updatedDate, tp.summary, IDENTITY(tp.author) as author")
            ->where('tp.url LIKE :url')
            ->andWhere('tp.public = 1')
            ->setParameter('url', $url."%")
            ->orderBy('tp.updatedDate', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Y el formato resultante es:

```
{
            "id": 2084,
            "url": "/url/del/post",
            "category": "259",
            "imageUrl": "url-imagen.png",
            "updatedDate": "2019-08-06T14:17:49+00:00",
            "summary": "resumen",
            "author": "4"
        }
```

La relación en la clase de las Entities están bien. De hecho si pido el objeto entero funciona bien. El problema es cuando selecciono campos específicos.

Comment: El problema es que no te muestra el objeto entero en el momento que le filtras campos específicos?

Comment: Igual me he explicado mal. cuando filtro por campos específicos no me muestra el objeto entero de la relación. En este caso me devuelve el id del Autor y no el Autor completo.

Comment: Intentaste hacer un dump del objeto autor?

Comment: dump($rquery->getAutor()) o dump($query['autor'])